# The SQL statement I use don't show the correct results using C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

Here is my code

```
public void onStart()
{
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _Annual_Rate", mydb);
    int counter = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM _Annual_Rate ", mydb);
    dt.Clear(); // Data Table = dt
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    DateTime[] date = new DateTime[counter];
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        date[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["Date_Of_Rate"]);
    }

    dateTimePicker1.MinDate = date.Min();
    dateTimePicker2.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;

    dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
    dateTimePicker2.MaxDate = date.Max();

    dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.MinDate;
    dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker2.MaxDate;
}

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dateTimePicker1.Value >= dateTimePicker2.Value)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.MinDate;
    }
    else
    {
        dateTimePicker2.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;

        DateTime minDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        DateTime maxDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM _Annual_Rate WHERE Date_Of_Rate BETWEEN #" + minDate + "# AND #" + maxDate + "#", mydb);

        dt.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        MessageBox.Show("minDate:" + minDate + "\nmaxDate:" + maxDate);
    }
}
```

Here is the results

[image: screenshot]

Here is my MS Access Database

[image: access screenshot]

I have coded dateTimePicker2 precisely the same as dateTimePicker1 with some minor changes to pass errors like `if (dateTimePicker2.Value <= dateTimePicker1.Value)`. Data disappear and reappear as I move through the calender that should not show or be gone. I can move dateTimePicker2 to the date 12/30/30 and then some dates will be gone where they should show or I move the date on dateTimePicker2 to 12/30/98 then the dates above it shows up. I can't find my error hopefully you can. The same with dateTimePicker1

Comment: First of all, you should not use string concatenation to build sql queries. Use ALWAYS a parameterized query. Second I would remove the BETWEEN and use a more precise >= and <=

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the BETWEEN and the string concatenation.
Instead I would use a parameterized query like this

```
DateTime minDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime maxDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM _Annual_Rate 
                   WHERE Date_Of_Rate >= ? AND Date_Of_Rage <= ?";
adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdText, mydb);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@d1", OleDbType.Date).Value = minDate;
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@d2", OleDbType.Date).Value = maxDate;
dt.Clear();
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

In this way the database engine will see the `minDate` and `maxDate` exactly as dates and not as some kind of string interpretation of a date value.
(There is also the added benefit to prevent Sql Injection albeit in MS-Access is more difficult to exploit)

Comment: I tried your code, its much better and closer then what I want. dateTimePicker1 works fully but dateTimePicker2 removes all the data if I pick day 30 or 31 and shows all the data on the other days does not matter which month or year I pick.

Comment: Notice that <= means that every date less than the choosen date at midnight because time is integral part of a datetime variable. Try to change the maxDate to be `maxDate = dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1);` to include also the full day of the maxDate